# Retrieving Azure Cost on daily basis using Python

Tags: python, sql, azure-billing

I am trying to fetch Azure Cost Usage data on daily basis using Python but I facing an error while trying to run the code

Error being generated :
query_ops = client.operations.query
AttributeError: 'Operations' object has no attribute 'query'

```
client = CostManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

# Query for yesterday's cost
query = "SELECT sum(cost) as cost FROM cost where time >= '{}' and time <=    '{}'".format(yesterday_start, yesterday_end)
query_ops = client.operations.query
query_result = query_ops.execute(query)

# Extract the cost from the query result
cost = query_result.results[0]["cost"]["value"]

# Append the cost and subscription ID to the data list
data.append({'subscription_id': subscription_id, 'cost': cost})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not substitute the 'query_usage' method for the 'query' method to retrieve the Cost Usage data.

Note: The client.usage object returned by CostManagementClient has a query method that you can use to execute your query. The query method takes your query as a parameter and returns a QueryResponse object that you can use to extract the results.

Replace:

```
query_ops = client.operations.query
query_result = query_ops.execute(query)
```

With:

```
query_ops = client.usage
query_result = query_ops.query(query)
```

Comment: using this -query_ops = client.usage
query_result = query_ops.query(query), gives another error - AttributeError: 'CostManagementClient' object has no attribute 'usage'